# Função de soma retorna zero

Tags: c, array, algoritmo

Até o momento do input está tudo ok com a informação, porém no output só dá o resultado 0 e não sei mais o que fazer, já mexi e remexi o código todo.

A ideia é que em um *array* de dimensão 6, ocorra a soma interna desses elementos. No caso os elementos são `{1,2,3,4,10,11}`.

```
int simpleArraySum(int ar_count, int ar [6]) {
ar_count = 0;
ar [0]= 1 ;
ar [1]= 2;
ar [2]= 3;
ar [3]= 4;
ar [4]= 10;
ar [5]= 11;
int i ;
int result;

for (i=0; i<6; i++){
    ar_count += ar[i];

};

result = ar_count;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse código é confuso e não faz sentido. Se fizer o simples, fazendo só o necessário de acordo com o enunciado, dando nomes mais significativos para as variáveis fica mais fácil. Nem estava retornando um valor obtido, ele só retornava 0, não dá para esperar um resultado diferente quando o código claramente faz isso. Inicie s soma, vai acumulando (e não contando) e retorno o resultado, só isso:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int simpleArraySum(int array[6]) {
    int soma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) soma += array[i];
    return soma;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d", simpleArraySum((int[]){1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11}));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bQ4V8D). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Accumulate2c). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Accumulate2.c).

Comment: Sim, ficou mais limpo assim, mas aí no caso ele não reconhece o vetor...A ideia que tive ali em cima foi declarar cada composição do vetor exatamente porque ele não lia quando eu declarava dentro das chaves.

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:15:60: error: taking address of temporary array

Esse foi o erro que apareceu para mim quando joguei no compilador. Só copiei, colei e dei run e deu esse erro. Não sei porque ele não lê o vetor em chaves.

Comment: Se você está fazendo algo em C porque tem um `.cpp`? Você clicou nos *links* e viu funcionando?

Comment: Hm...selecionei errado na hora de abrir o Dev-c++, valeu cara! Ajudou muito :)